# Crash while converting html to string in UILabel in IOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel

I have Home Page/view where I display all the records (only title and date) in a listview.

When I click on any record I display complete information of record in another page.
Each and every record has a html string value which needs to be displayed.

To display html content I use UILabel control which gets displayed correctly.

But when Navigation is done back and forth between 2 pages/views it crashes.
The crash report is pointing to memory related to issues.

```
modifiedContent = [modifiedContent stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>",@"Helvetica",17.0f]];

content.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[modifiedContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                              options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                              documentAttributes:nil
                              error:nil];
```

Is there a need to change the above code to handle memory leakage or is there a need of different encoding type.

It needs to be supported from IOS 7 to IOS Current Version

Below is the stack Trace

```
MyAppName(1098,0x39d7000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=151552) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
MyAppName(1098,0x39d7000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=151552) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
2015-11-19 10:18:59.643 MyAppName[1098:436403] -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76954080
2015-11-19 10:18:59.646 MyAppName[1098:436403] -[NSCoder(CACoderAdditions) CA_encodeObject:forKey:conditional:]: ignoring exception -[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76954080
2015-11-19 10:18:59.650 MyAppName[1098:436403] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key ''; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
2015-11-19 10:18:59.660 MyAppName[1098:436403] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key ''; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
2015-11-19 10:18:59.662 MyAppName[1098:436403] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key ''; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
2015-11-19 10:18:59.675 MyAppName[1098:436403] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key ''; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
2015-11-19 10:18:59.677 MyAppName[1098:436403] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key ''; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
2015-11-19 10:18:59.785 MyAppName[1098:436403] *** NSKeyedArchiver warning: replacing existing value for key ''; probable duplication of encoding keys in class hierarchy
(lldb)
```

Comment: What are these "memory related" issues? Where does the crash occur? What does the exception (if any) say? Is the code compiled using ARC? If non, then there's a memory leak.

Comment: The Xcode version i am using is 8.3 and the iphone version is 9.1 hence i am not able to run the code directly from xcode. the project is not ARC compiled.

I have edited my question which contains the stack trace generated from Crittercism

Answer (score 0):

Since you state that the code doesn't use ARC, you're leaking a `NSAttributedString` instance every time the quoted code is run. To fix this, you can do this (I'm using an unorthodox formatting here to make it slightly more readable here on SO; adapt it to your coding style, please):

```
NSAttributedString *attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
    initWithData:[modifiedContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]        
    options:@{
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }                          
    documentAttributes:nil                          
    error:nil];
content.attributedText = attributed;
[attributed release];
```

(Also: use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` or at least be consistent *which* you're using; you've created data using one encoding but told in the options that it would be in another encoding.)

Comment: Sorry the code uses ARC, i have changed the encoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding. But still from the crash it looks the memory is getting leaked. How to free memory even when ARC is used.

Comment: The leak must be somewhere else, then. Use Instruments with the Leaks Tool to find it.